# Append multiple items in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I have the following function and I am trying to figure out a better way to append multiple items using `appendChild()`.

When the user clicks on Add, each item should look like this:

```
<li>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <label>Content typed by the user</label>
  <input type="text">
  <button class="edit">Edit</button>
  <button class="delete">Delete</button>
</li>
```

and I have this function to add these elements:

```
function addNewItem(listElement, itemInput) {
  var listItem = document.createElement("li");
  var listItemCheckbox = document.createElement("input");
  var listItemLabel = document.createElement("label");
  var editableInput = document.createElement("input");
  var editButton = document.createElement("button");
  var deleteButton = document.createElement("button");

  // define types
  listItemCheckbox.type = "checkbox";
  editableInput.type = "text";

  // define content and class for buttons
  editButton.innerText = "Edit";
  editButton.className = "edit";
  deleteButton.innerText = "Delete";
  deleteButton.className = "delete";

  listItemLabel.innerText = itemText.value;

  // appendChild() - append these items to the li
  listElement.appendChild(listItem);
  listItem.appendChild(listItemCheckbox);
  listItem.appendChild(listItemLabel);
  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);

  if (itemText.value.length > 0) {
    itemText.value = "";
    inputFocus(itemText);
  }
}
```

But you can notice that I am repeating three times the `appendChild()` for `listItem`. Is it possible to add multiple items to the `appendChild()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598916/speed-efficiency-of-multiple-dom-appendchild

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally, I don't see why you would do this.

But if you really need to replace all the `appendChild()` with one statement, you can assign the `outerHTML` of the created elements to the `innerHTML` of the `li` element.

You just need to replace the following:

```
  listElement.appendChild(listItem);
  listItem.appendChild(listItemCheckbox);
  listItem.appendChild(listItemLabel);
  listItem.appendChild(editButton);
  listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

With the following:

```
listItem.innerHTML+= listItemCheckbox.outerHTML + listItemLabel.outerHTML + editButton.outerHTML + deleteButton.outerHTML;
listElement.appendChild(listItem);
```

**Explanation:**

The **outerHTML** attribute of the element DOM interface gets the serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its descendants. So assigning the `outerHTML` of the created elements to the `innerHTML` of the `li` element is similar to appending them to it.

Comment: This does not actually append the children, but instead a copy of them, which loses properties.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbertwhat properties are lost? I don't get it. It does what should be done.

Comment: Set a property like `listCheckbox.asdf = 5; listItem.innerHTML = listCheckbox.outerHTML; listItem.querySelector('input').asdf === 5` and it will be false because properties (unlike attributes) are not found in the outerHTML.  For input items, the most important property lost is `.value` (different from attribute "value").  Also event listeners, etc.  For many purposes (including here), your solution works, but it does lose properties and is much slower.

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert Yes I understand what you mean you are right, but I meant here it was only needed to handle the HTML objects tree.

Comment: I think this should overall be avoided. If you register any event listeners or references to the DOM elements, all of these are lost by using `innerHTML` and this can cause unexpected behaviour in your application in the future.

Comment: @undefined yes of course, my answer what just to provide a quick solution to handle the OP request.

Answer (score 112):

You can do it with [DocumentFragment](https://davidwalsh.name/documentfragment).

```
var documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
documentFragment.appendChild(listItem);
listItem.appendChild(listItemCheckbox);
listItem.appendChild(listItemLabel);
listItem.appendChild(editButton);
listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
listElement.appendChild(documentFragment);
```

> DocumentFragments allow developers to place child elements onto an
>   arbitrary node-like parent, allowing for node-like interactions
>   without a true root node.  Doing so allows developers to produce
>   structure without doing so within the visible DOM

Comment: But none of those `appendChild` calls take place in the live DOM, so the browser won't try to re-render the entire DOM after each child is appended. Instead, only a single re-render takes place after the entire fragment is appended.

Comment: Great answer - DocumentFragment is a very useful way of batching changes to the rendered DOM.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it uses the DOM API instead of strings. Very cool answer. Thank you.

Comment: mozilla doc: [Document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

Comment: Wow thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 64):

You can use the [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method in JavaScript.

This is similar to jQuery's append method but it doesnot support IE and Edge.

You can change this code

```
listElement.appendChild(listItem);
listItem.appendChild(listItemCheckbox);
listItem.appendChild(listItemLabel);
listItem.appendChild(editButton);
listItem.appendChild(deleteButton);
```

to

```
listElement.append(listItem,listItemCheckbox,listItemLabel,editButton,deleteButton);
```

Comment: this is just awesome but too bad IE still doesn't support it.

Comment: As of Jan 2019 `append` is broadly supported but it is not standardized and considered an experimental technology. it should be used carefully

Comment: @skzryzg I think it is not experimental any more what I see from `mdn`.

Answer (score 14):

Merging the answers by @Atrahasis and @Slavik:

```js
if (Node.prototype.appendChildren === undefined) {
  Node.prototype.appendChildren = function() {
    let children = [...arguments];

    if (
      children.length == 1 &&
      Object.prototype.toString.call(children[0]) === "[object Array]"
    ) {
      children = children[0];
    }

    const documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    children.forEach(c => documentFragment.appendChild(c));
    this.appendChild(documentFragment);
  };
}
```

This accepts children as multiple arguments, or as a single array argument:

```js
foo.appendChildren(bar1, bar2, bar3);
bar.appendChildren([bar1, bar2, bar3]);
```

---

### Update – June 2020

Most all current browsers support [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) and the ["spread operator"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) now.

The calls above can be re-written as:

```js
foo.append(bar1, bar2, bar3);
bar.append(...[bar1, bar2, bar3]);
```

Comment: P.S. ES6+ only and I'm sure this could be written in a better way. Spreading the nodes into an array/only accepting an array for the singular argument code path (mostly in order to use `forEach`) is probably pretty bad. Also, adding a function to Node.prototype/similar is probably something you shouldn't do.

Comment: I wrapped the polyfill in an existence condition. I think it is fine to add it to `Node` because `Node` is the object that defines `appendChild`. Although [Sagar V's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45215917/1762224) response is the best way, especially with support from the spread operator. I added an updated version to the end of your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let's try this:

```
let parentNode = document.createElement('div');

parentNode.append(...[
    document.createElement('div'),
    document.createElement('div'),
    document.createElement('div'),
    document.createElement('div'),
    document.createElement('div')
]);

console.log(parentNode);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to append several children ? Just make it plural with `appendChildren` !

First things first :

```
HTMLLIElement.prototype.appendChildren = function () {

  for ( var i = 0 ; i < arguments.length ; i++ )

    this.appendChild( arguments[ i ] );

};
```

Then for any list element :

```
listElement.appendChildren( a, b, c, ... );

//check :
listElement.childNodes;//a, b, c, ...
```

Works with every element that has the `appendChild` method of course ! Like `HTMLDivElement`.

Comment: It would be nice to combine this with the DocumentFragment in Slavik's answer to keep the multiple appendChild calls out of the main DOM.

Comment: @AndFinally - Genuinely curious/not sure: why? Cheaper operationally to repetitively add to a fragment than the DOM?

Comment: @RockinSocks Appending a series of nodes to a fragment and only appending the fragment once everything's put together avoids the browser having to do several recalculations of the position and size of elements on the page, i.e. doing several reflows. This way, the reflow only happens once, when you append the fragment to the live DOM. So the change should render faster. See here for a quick explanation - https://www.sitepoint.com/10-ways-minimize-reflows-improve-performance/.

Comment: @AndFinally Is this actually true for modern browsers? I would imagine browser will be smart enough to hold updates if there's a sequence of DOM changes happening in the single execution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use createContextualFragment, it return a documentFragment created from a string.
It is perfect if you have to build and append more than one `Node`s to an existing `Element` all together, because you can add it all without the cons of `innerHTML`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment

```
// ...
var listItem = document.createElement("li");
var documentFragment = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
    <input type="checkbox">
    <label>Content typed by the user</label>
    <input type="text">
    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
    <button class="delete">Delete</button>
`)
listItem.appendChild(documentFragment)
// ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Why isn't anybody mentioning the `element.append()` function ?!

you can simply use it to append multiple items respectively as so:

```js
listItem.append(listItemCheckbox, listItemLabel, editButton, deleteButton);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could just group the elements into a single innerHTML group like this:

```
  let node = document.createElement('li');
  node.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox"><label>Content typed by the user</label>  <input type="text"><button class="edit">Edit</button><button class="delete">Delete</button>';
  document.getElementById('orderedList').appendChild(node);
```

then appendChild() is only used once.

Comment: Be aware that doing so will remove any event listener attached to the appended nodes, as innerHTML does not retain these, unlike appendChild.

Comment: @ojathelonius, that is irrelevant: the node is *created* here, so it does not have any event listeners any way.

Comment: I'm not talking about the node that is created here, but about its content. `innerHTML` does not retain any attached event listener.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to write your own function if you use the built in [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

```
function appendMultipleNodes(){
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
  for (var x = 1; x < args.length; x++){
      args[0].appendChild(args[x])
  }
  return args[0]
}
```

Then you would call the function as such:

```
appendMultipleNodes(parent, nodeOne, nodeTwo, nodeThree)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also here's a helper function that uses the fragment technique as introduced in the @Slavik's answer and merges it with DOMParser API:

```js
function createHtmlFromString(stringHtml) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const htmlFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const children = parser.parseFromString(stringHtml, "text/html").body
    .children;
  htmlFragment.replaceChildren(...children);
  return htmlFragment;
}
```

Now to append multiple children with this, you can make the code much more readable and brief, e.g.:

```js
  const htmlFragment = createHtmlFromString(`<div class="info">
      <span></span>
      <h2></h2>
      <p></p>
      <button></button>
    </div>
    <div class="cover">
      <img />
    </div>
  `);
```

Here's also a working example of these used in action: [example link](https://github.com/aderchox/ctst-221304/blob/p7-internationalization-multi-lingual-games-showcase/dynamic.js).

**Note1:** You could add text content in the above tags too and it works, but if it's data from user (or fetched from API), you'd better not trust it for better security. Instead, first make the fragment using the above function and then do something like this:

```
  htmlFragment.querySelector(".info > span").textContent = game.name;
```

**Note2:** Don't use innerHTML to insert HTML, it is [unsecure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#security_considerations).

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix

```
document.querySelector("#parentid .parenClass").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', yourChildElement.outerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I really recommend you to use this one.

```js
[listItemCheckbox, listItemLabel, editButton, deleteButton]
.forEach((item) => listItem.appendChild(item));
```

Since you can't append multiple children at once. I think this one looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Great way to dynamically add elements to a webpage. This function takes 3 arguments, 1  is optional. The wrapper will wrap the parent element and it's elements inside another element. Useful when creating tables dynamically.

```js
  function append(parent, child, wrapper="") {
    if (typeof child == 'object' && child.length > 1) {
      child.forEach(c => {
        parent.appendChild(c);
      });
    } else {
      parent.appendChild(child);
    }
    if (typeof wrapper == 'object') {
      wrapper.appendChild(parent);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add that if you want to add some variability to your html, you can also add variables like this:

```
let node = document.createElement('div');
node.classList.add("some-class");
node.innerHTML = `<div class="list">
                  <div class="title">${myObject.title}</div>
                  <div class="subtitle">${myObject.subtitle}
                </div>`;
```